# how to access global variable from function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access global variable from function, i want to call variable outside from inside function variable.This is what I tried.
Note: the query function should be work after click on query function from html drop down selection.
Thank you for helping.

```
HTML
<select  name="myInput" id="choice1">
       <li><option value="6011">apib_cadastral:bivel</option></li>
       <li><option value="6012">apib_cadastral:burhchaura</option></li>
 </select>

javascript
var layer_name;
function query() {
  var text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
  var layer_name = text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
}
query();
var config = {
  geojson: layer_name,
};
```

Comment: Exactly how you've done it in the object literal, just using variable's name, don't declare it again in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the "var" inside the function. With that you define a new variable that exists inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code in this way.
Because, when you re-declare variable inside query() it will occupy another cell from memory with different address. And, variable inside config object cannot access it. It will access layer_name [first defined] which contains undefined value

```
var layer_name ;
function query() {
    var text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0]
    layer_name = text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
}
query();
var config = {
geojson: layer_name
}
```

Comment: actually here  my problem is different, whenever I select from drop down i have to get text into a variable like that.The above code generate only which is  first from drop down.

Comment: This way Im trying to get text from drop down.                                                    
   <select  name="myInput" id="choice1">
       <li><option value="6011">apib_cadastral:bivel</option></li>
       <li><option value="6012">apib_cadastral:burhchaura</option></li>
 </select>

Comment: Please check once my asked question there I have attached html,JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, which correctly state that you should remove `var` from the variable declaration inside the `query()` function, you could change the function to return the value, rather than relying on shared/global state.

```
function query() {
  var text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
  return text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
}

var config = {
  geojson: query()
};
```

Note that this *may* have a performance impact depending on how many times you call `query()` as the return value would have to be computed each time, but it's worth considering from the perspective of alleviating the need for shared/global state.

Also note, consider replacing `var` with more modern `const` and `let`...

- `const` when the variable is initialised and never needs to change.
- `let` when the variable needs to change beyond initialisation.

```
function query() {
  const text_value = document.getElementsByName('myInput')[0];
  return text_value.options[text_value.selectedIndex].text;
}

const config = {
  geojson: query()
};
```